# Looping through a pointer array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a pointer array, and I want to set all values to `0`.

Here is my code:

```
#define EMPTY 0

void initBoard(int *ptr, int n){

n = n * n;
ptr = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
int i = 0;
for(i;i<n;i++){
    *ptr = EMPTY;
    *ptr++;
}
i = 0;
for(i;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
    *ptr++;
}

}
```

when running this code, I expect to get (N == 0):

```
0
0
0
0
```

instead I get this:

```
394066110
7321
6890384
6881472
```

Why am I getting this?

EDIT:

```
void printBoard(int *ptr){

printf("%d - %d - %d\n", ptr, ptr+1, ptr+2);
printf("%d - %d - %d\n", ptr+3, ptr+4, ptr+5);
printf("%d - %d - %d\n", ptr+6, ptr+7, ptr+8);

}
```

will print out:

```
0 - 4 - 8
12 - 16 - 20
24 - 28 - 32
```

here is how it looks when i call the funtion:

```
    int *ptr, win = 0;

initBoard(*ptr);
printBoard(*ptr);
```

EDIT 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//define
#define EMPTY 0
#define CROSS 1
#define CIRCLE 2
#define NO_WIN 0
#define PLAYER_WIN 1
#define COMPUTER_WIN 2
#define DRAW 3

//funktioner
void printBoard(int *ptr);
int checkWin(int *ptr);
void computerMove(int *ptr);
void initBoard(int *ptr);

int main()
{
    int *ptr, win = 0;

    initBoard(*ptr);
    printBoard(*ptr);

    return 0;
}

void printBoard(int *ptr){

    printf("%d - %d - %d\n", ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2]);


}

int checkWin(int *ptr){

    return 0;

}

void computerMove(int *ptr){

}

void initBoard(int *ptr){

    ptr = malloc(9*sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;
    //int *orig = ptr; //spara pointern
    for(i;i<9;i++){
        *ptr = EMPTY;
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Change this to `void initBoard(int *&ptr, int n){`, otherwise you're writing to a copy of the parameter.

Comment: @bkVnet i wnant to loop through the array

Comment: what is `EMPTY`. If you want to set to zero then do `*ptr = 0`. Is `EMPTY` defined to be zero. Also do `ptr++` instead of `*ptr++`

Comment: You forgot to reset `ptr` before the start of the second loop. Because you did not save a copy, you cannot, and nor can you `free(ptr)` either. So keep a copy of `ptr`.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been simpler to use `ptr[i]`? The entire code would then be easy to follow and frill-free.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is tagged C. OP would need `int **ptr`.

Comment: Another way to set all the values to `0` at the time you allocate memory, is by using `calloc`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Because someone retagged the question after my comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane how do i do that? could you explain please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok. I see that now.

Comment: @MosOm with `ptr = calloc(n, sizeof *ptr);`. Note that I use the size of the pointer's object, so that if you change the type you don't have to chase up where you used its object's size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the way the dereference operator `*` and post-increment operator `++` interact.

When you write this `*ptr++` you say "first, get me the writeable value at the pointer; then increment the pointer". This expression does not make sense by itself, because the result of dereferencing is discarded. In other words, it is equivalent to `ptr++`.

Now consider your second loop. Your pointer points to one past the end of the allocated block. At this point, dereferencing it is illegal.

You can fix this by storing the original pointer before coming into the first loop, and using the saved value to reset `ptr` before the second loop:

```
int i = 0;
int *orig = ptr; // Save the original pointer
for(i;i<n;i++){
    *ptr++ = EMPTY; // Combine ++ and * on assignment
}
i = 0;
ptr = orig; // Restore the original pointer
for(i;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d\n", *ptr++); // Combine ++ and * on read
}
```

If you would like `initiBoard` to initialize `ptr` that has not previously been set, change the signature as follows:

```
void initBoard(int **ptrPtr, int n);
```

Call `initBoard(&ptr, n)`, and use `ptrPtr` with an extra level of dereference, i.e.

```
*ptrPtr = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Hey, right after this code, if i try 'printf("%d - %d - %d\n", ptr++, ptr++, ptr++);' i get this '0 - 4- 8', why dont i get '0 - 0 - 0' ??

Comment: I still get the same answe using     ptr+1    .

Comment: pleas look at my question , I will edit in my new code

Comment: @MosOm I see, asterisks are missing: `printf("%d - %d - %d\n", *(ptr+0), *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2))`

Comment: @MosOm Even better, `printf("%d - %d - %d\n", ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2])`

Comment: When i execute the program, I get an error window saying main.exe is not responding, what could I do wrong here? I really appreciate your answer.